# AES128 encryption is not properly working with key and iv and giving different output than android produces after same encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, key, aes

> I am using below code to encrypt NSData with AES128 CBC encryption
>   with no padding with key and IV, its not giving the same output as
>   android whereas android's output is correct one.

```
- (NSData*)AES128Encrypt:(NSData *)dataToEncrypt iv:(NSString *)iv key:(NSString *)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    if (iv) {
        [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [dataToEncrypt length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          ccNoPadding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [dataToEncrypt bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do Base64 decoding for the Key and IV.

Comment: I am passing Key and IV as a string, still I will need to do the decoding for it or you intended to say encoding?

Comment: First you check with an online tool. Try to decrypt the message and check it it matches for both languages. You can check with Base64 decoding for key and IV, in the below line -  [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Can you send me the code you want me to add that would help me better, Thanks for the help.